# Get the latest prop in event callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible and how to get the updated prop in event callback function?

I could add `number` prop to list of effect dependencies but then the event listener is re-added on every update (and removed but logic is missing for the sake of simplicity).

Maybe it could be hacked with `useRef` somehow?

#### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dwveyfb/)

```
function Scroll({ number }) {
  function onScroll(e) {
    // how to update number prop
    // without removing and
    // re-adding event listener?

    // it's always the value first
    // time passed as number prop
    console.log(number);
  }

  const scrollEl = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    scrollEl.current = document.getElementById('scroll');
    scrollEl.current.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="scroll">
      <div className="content" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Note:** I cannot use React's synthetic events in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `onScroll` function.

Tweak your Scroll component to:

```
function Scroll({ number }) {
  this.number = number;
  function onScroll(e) {
    // how to update number prop
    // without removing and
    // re-adding event listener?
    console.log(this.number);
  }

  const scrollEl = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    scrollEl.current = document.getElementById('scroll');
    scrollEl.current.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll.bind(this));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="scroll">
      <div className="content" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you aren't comfortable with using `this` you could change to a different object.

Comment: Could you demonstrate it in JSFiddle I have in my question? Im unable to apply this answer successfully because `this` is `window` in functional components (in my particular example).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/47mo3fn8/10/, FYI - I have changed the order of the scroll container and the button to test.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/47mo3fn8/11, if you want to try with a different object other than `this`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see `this.number = number;`, it all makes sense now.